# Android's SurfaceView blinks

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I want to create simple Android application which will draw circles in place where I touch the screen. It is working with View (slowly), but with SurfaceView not. The result is strange - when clicking, whole image is moving. I also tried to call drawing function from another thread, but results are the same. Also found another example with this strange behavior:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-surfaceview.html
I work with Android 2.3.3, API level 10. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.samsung.sketchbook;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SketchBook extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BookView bookView = new BookView(this);
        setContentView(bookView);
    }

    class BookView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private float x, y;

        public BookView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d("BookView", "surfaceCreated!");
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            x = motionEvent.getX();
            y = motionEvent.getY();
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 3, paint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Dude, have you solved the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend you don't use `SurfaceView`.

My experience say that it isn't a better solution than `View`.  Yes, implementation class which extends on `View` is slowly, *but* only when you don't know how to effectively use `invalidate()`.

I mean don't use `invalidate()` (which draws all canvas), but `invalidate(dirtyRect)` (You define the rectangular which you want to redraw, and the rest of the canvas stays just like before) it's very fast.